O que significa genolexical?
Tentei ler alguns trabalhos de linguistica que usam a palavra genolexical mas (como é habitual com trabalhos científicos) a definição do termo não é incluida em nenhum dos textos que tenho encontrado.
Se tentarmos ver no priberam a palavra também não é definida:

genolexical
adjectivo de dois géneros
(A definição desta palavra estará disponível brevemente. Envie comentários ou sugestões para dicionario@priberam.pt)

A minha pergunta é: afinal o que é genolexical?

Proponho:
"Relativo à formação de palavras.", ou talvez:
"Relativo à criação/formação/geração/produção do léxico ou dos vocábulos do léxico."
É o que deduzo da aparente etimologia de "genolexical": geno- + léxico + -al, em que "léxico" é "vocabulário", "-al" adjetiva e "geno-" denota origem. Comparável com "lexicogênico".
E é também como entendo que é usado na introdução do artigo "Operações e paradigmas genolexicais do português" (1998). Filologia E Linguística Portuguesa, 2, 39-60. https://doi.org/10.11606/issn.2176-9419.v0i2p39-60, minha ênfase:

a formação de palavras apresenta-se como um domínio de acentuada complexidade, decorrente não apenas das variáveis com que opera mas também da capacidade gerativa por que se define, e que a designação de “sector/componente genolexical” sublinha.


Esses procedimentos necessariamente actuantes em cada sistema genolexical e muitos dos quais comuns a diversas línguas, são os processos de produção lexical.


as regras de formação [de palavras] são freqüentemente identificadas como paradigmas genolexicais.


Acho que o sentido do termo ficou esclarecido.
